# Does Apachge Ignite SQL support MERGE WHEN?

Tags: sql, ignite

Apache Ignite SQL supports the MERGE statement.  Does this support extend to MERGE WHEN (e.g. as in H2)?  e.g.

```
 MERGE INTO account (client_id, tran_ccy, last_tran_dt)
  (SELECT DISTINCT client_id, tran_ccy, Max(tran_dt) 
   FROM transaction
   GROUP BY client_id, tran_ccy)
 WHEN MATCHED THEN 
   UPDATE SET last_tran_dt = tran_dt
 WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
   INSERT (client_id, tran_ccy, last_tran_dt)
   VALUES (client_id, tran_ccy, tran_dt)
```

Comment: https://apacheignite-sql.readme.io/docs/merge

Comment: Yes, I've seen that doc and it does not mention the WHEN clause, either way.  I have asked the question because Ignite SQL is based on SQL-99 which includes MERGE WHEN.  I'm also aware that Ignite employs H2 in its SQL implementation, and H2 does MERGE WHEN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know Ignite supports only simple `MERGE` from `H2` without `USING` statement. 
Here is the syntax of simple form http://www.h2database.com/html/commands.html#merge. It's also described here https://apacheignite-sql.readme.io/docs/merge.

Comment: Thanks, Vladimir.